# Jest jsdom Protocol "http:" not supported

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom, ts-jest, msw

I am trying to run some integration tests for react using jest. When running the test, I get the following error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"`  . Initially I though was related to msw mocking my api calls, but even after disabling the msw server I am still getting this erros.

I am using axios in my app to make http requests, and all URLs are set to use HTTPS. I also told jest both in a setup file and `jest.config` to use https when mocking origin, but it's still not working. Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Instead of doing the actual `http` calls you can mock `axios` and check whether your app is requesting the correct endpoint with the correct data and mock the responses